# Can't run Spark 1.2 in standalone mode on Mac

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to learn Spark by running it in standalone mode on my MacBook Pro (10.9.2). I downloaded & built it using the instructions here:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html

I then started up the master server using the instructions here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually

That worked, although I had to add the following line to my SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh file to get it to start successfully:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_IP="127.0.0.1"
```

However, when I try to execute this command to start a worker:

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://127.0.0.1:7077
```

It fails with this error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/01/26 16:29:17 INFO Worker: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
15/01/26 16:29:17 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: erioconnor
15/01/26 16:29:17 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: erioconnor
15/01/26 16:29:17 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(erioconnor); users with modify permissions: Set(erioconnor)
15/01/26 16:29:17 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/01/26 16:29:17 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/01/26 16:29:17 ERROR NettyTransport: failed to bind to /10.252.181.130:0, shutting down Netty transport
15/01/26 16:29:17 ERROR Remoting: Remoting error: [Startup failed] [
akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: Startup failed
    at akka.remote.Remoting.akka$remote$Remoting$$notifyError(Remoting.scala:136)
    at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:201)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:184)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:618)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:615)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:615)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:632)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1676)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1667)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$.startSystemAndActor(Worker.scala:495)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$.main(Worker.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker.main(Worker.scala)
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /10.252.181.130:0
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:393)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:389)
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:372)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]
15/01/26 16:29:17 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkWorker' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
15/01/26 16:29:17 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
15/01/26 16:29:17 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
15/01/26 16:29:17 INFO Remoting: Remoting shut down
15/01/26 16:29:17 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
```

The error repeats a grand total of 16 times before the process gives up.

I don't understand the reference to IP address 10.252.181.130. It doesn't appear anywhere in the Spark code/config that I've been able to locate, and Googling it doesn't turn up any results. I noticed this line in the log file from when I started the master server:

```
15/01/26 16:27:18 INFO MasterWebUI: Started MasterWebUI at http://10.252.181.130:8080
```

I looked at the Scala source for MasterWebUI (and WebUI, which it extends), and noticed that they seem to get that IP address from an environment variable called SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS. I tried setting that variable to 127.0.0.1 in my spark-env.sh script, but that didn't work. In fact, it prevented my master server from starting:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/01/26 19:46:16 INFO Master: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: LM-PDX-00871419: LM-PDX-00871419: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalIpAddress(Utils.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:612)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddress(Utils.scala:612)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddressHostname$lzycompute(Utils.scala:613)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddressHostname(Utils.scala:613)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:665)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.MasterArguments.<init>(MasterArguments.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$.main(Master.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.main(Master.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: LM-PDX-00871419: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
    ... 12 more
```

(Note that LM-PDX-00871419 is the hostname of my Mac.)

So at this point I'm kinda stumped. I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions as to where to look next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had trouble using the loopback address, `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. I've had better success with the actual public IP address of the machine, e.g., `192.168.1.101`. I don't know where the `10.252.181.130` is coming from, either.

For your Mac's host name, try adding ".local" to end. If that doesn't work, add an entry to `/etc/hosts`.

Finally, I recommend using the `sbin/spark-master.sh` and `sbin/spark-slave.sh` scripts for running these services.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried using my private IP address first (192.168.1.13), but that didn't work. However, it led me to the discovery that there's another environment variable called SPARK_LOCAL_IP that's apparently getting used. When I tried setting that to 127.0.0.1 in my spark-env.sh file, I was able to get my master and worker started.

Answer (score 5):

If you use IntelliJ IDEA, it might be helpful to know that one can set the environment variable SPARK_LOCAL_IP to 127.0.0.1 in Run/Debug configurations.